# How to set PDO default host?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, php-ini

I'm trying to convert some PHP code from Mysqli to PDO, and I need to be able to set a default host for PDO MySQL connections (outside of my application code).

With Mysqli, I could do this with the `php.ini` setting:

```
mysqli.default_host = ip.of.mysql.server
```

And then connect with:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(null,  USERNAME,  PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

It's worked beautifully for us.

---

The equivalent code for PDO:

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Doesn't work the same way.  It works as long as my MySQL server is on localhost.  It isn't. I have a separate machine hosting my MySQL server.

Is there an equivalent `php.ini` setting that could accomplish what I need for PDO? The closest thing I've found is a [pdo_mysql.default_socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#ini.pdo-mysql.default-socket) setting, but I don't think that will do it.

Comment: You could use a host and change the IP address in the hosts file. That's outside of application code.

Comment: Seems a little hacky to me, but if there's no official way to do this, I'll probably go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PDO documentation, you can set pdo.dsn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.configuration.php#ini.pdo.dsn) aliases in php.ini.

In php.ini:

```
pdo.dsn.mydb="mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost"
```

In PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mydb', $user, $password);
```

Alternatively, you could use a host and change the IP address in the hosts file. That's outside of application code.

Comment: By "change the IP address in the hosts file", do you really mean that `localhost` should point to anything else, than the local machine?

Comment: I think he meant whatever domain I wanted to use other than localhost.

Comment: Yeah, use an actual host name other than `localhost`. If you changed the IP for localhost, that would be confusing. :)

Comment: And I imagine a _lot_ of things would break ;-)

Comment: Answer accepted.  Had to go the hosts route.  I'm disappointed that PDO doesn't offer a way to do this, but there is a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Socket connections are only useful on local connections only. You must specify the host explicitly

```
mysql:host=123.123.123.1;dbname=MyDb
```

Update: Just found something

http://php.net/pdo.configuration

As far as I can see you can define alias for dsns. I didn't try it myself, but it should look like

```
pdo.dsn.otherServer = mysql:host=example.com;dbname=foo
```

And then you should be able to use it in [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/pdo.construct)

```
$pdo = new PDO('otherServer', $x, $y);
```

Additional you can give a file path as constructor argument, that points to a file that contains the dsn-string

```
$pdo = new PDO('uri:file///usr/share/connection.dsn', $x, $y);
// With file /usr/share/connection.dsn that contains: (and nothing more than)
mysql:host=example.com;dbname=foo
```

Comment: That's what I figured. I know that I can supply the host explicitly. What I'm looking for is a way to set a default host somewhere outside of my application code a la Mysqli. I'm really hoping this is possible.

Comment: Regarding your edit: That's perfect! I'll test that out right now.

Comment: Must say: Didn't realized it before. Sounds quite cool to me too :) That allows to separate the database (configuration) from the application and bind it to the environment directly.

Comment: Arg! So close, yet so far. It does work, but now my database name is outside the application as well, which right now is dynamically referenced in the code (and needs to be).  It doesn't look like I can separate the two.  It's either all out or all in. I may have to go the hosts file route.

Comment: How dynamic should the database name be? You can define as many alias as you like. If you have 5 databases, why you just don't define 5 alias? Or maybe have a look at the second solution: Write your several databases into separate files and load them via the `uri:`-style dsn.

Comment: The problem is that the application uses the same code on multiple servers for multiple "insallations" which are designated by sub-domain. The sub-domain corresponds to the database name, the user, and a single config file with the database password. With the alias scenario, I would have to put a new line in PHP.ini for each installation (and on each server) in addition to the config file. With the file route, I'd then need two config files, one of which could not be synchronized between servers because its contents would have to be different on each. The Mysqli setup was/is perfect for us.